# IOS: How to show and play video from JSON

Tags: ios, json, video, uiwebview

in my project i have to display `videos` which are coming from `JSON` Response in the form of url like ("http://eyeforweb.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/myconnect/index.php?do=/video/63/video-videovideo/")

The problem is when i want to show it in `UIWebView` it shows nothing and when i tried second method i get the same result

please help me to show and play video

Currently i am using the following code:

```
NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://eyeforweb.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/myconnect/index.php?do=/video/63/video-videovideo/"];

    _streamPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];

    // depending on your implementation your view may not have it's bounds set here
    // in that case consider calling the following 4 msgs later
    [self.streamPlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(15, 75, VidScroll.frame.size.width-30, 300)];

    self.streamPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

    [VidScroll addSubview: self.streamPlayer.view];

    [self.streamPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you got the html instead of the video's url(as you mentioned, `JSON`).

For your convenience, i get the video's url: 
[d607c47e50827b3a90e3a24442c72dae.flv](http://eyeforweb.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/myconnect/file/video/2016/11/d607c47e50827b3a90e3a24442c72dae.flv)

Comment: thanks but how it is converted? as i have an array of this type of video links

Comment: @Abhi If you have an backend server, you can write a crawler to get the videos' urls and store theme into the database, and you can get an JSON including the videos' urls.

Comment: @Abhi You can also parse the dom of the video's url in you app with some dom parsing tools. Here is [a tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)

Comment: if possible please update your answer how i apply this to my code as when i tried to put this url directly into my above code it shows black screen

Comment: @Abhi FYI, `FLV`' is Flash video, and cocoa's `MPMoviePlayerController ` can't play it. You'd better get an player use `ffmpeg` as its backend to play this kind of videos.

Answer (score 1):

Check by printing the length of the streamPlayer to see if you are really loading a video.

Code sample: (not tested)

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:streamURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
if (error) {
   NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
   NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
   NSLog(@"Bytes %ld",data.count);
}
```

Otherwise wait a few seconds/have a notification when the video is loaded. It is possible that the vid just didn't arrived.

Comment: its not working please suggest me any code by which i can show and play video coming from json response in my app

Comment: from the above code it gives the following output : -=-=Data has loaded successfully.-=-=- and  Bytes -=-=-= 140385435954176 but video is still not appears please help

Comment: If that number is correct, it is a very very large file. Maybe that gives some memory error, although the error flag is not triggered. You can try it with a smaller Vid (from YouTube).

Comment: it is not a big file it is just 5-6 second clip d607c47e50827b3a90e3a24442c72dae.flv